# Corsair flash drive not detected

Tags: usb-flash-drive, hdtv

I have a Corsair Flash Voyager 16 GB USB 2.0 which I am trying to use with my Samsung HDTV's (Model: [LA40C530F1RMXL](http://www.samsung.com/my/support/detail/supportPrdDetail.do?menu=SP01&prd_ia_cd=&prd_mdl_cd=&prd_mdl_name=LA40C530F1R)) Media Play functionality. The problem is that the TV doesn't seem to detect (or power) the flash drive via its USB port since the LED on the flash drive doesn't light up and it doesn't appear in the 'Sources' list.

I don't think the problem is with the TV since I have been able to plug in a variety of other storage devices ranging from 512 MB flash drive to a 1 TB external HDD, with FAT, FAT32 and NTFS filesystems and successfully use them as media sources.

I have formatted my pen drive in both FAT32 and NTFS formats, using both quick format and long format. Then copied a single DivX file (which worked played perfectly in other thumb drives connected to the TV) and plugged it in my TV but it didn't work. I have tried to use the pen drive with other HDTVs but it didn't work with them either. So far, I had only used this pen drive with computers where it worked perfectly. How do I make the thumb drive work with the HDTV ?

**Update:** I updated the HDTV to the latest firmware and plugged in the thumb drive. Still not functioning.

Comment: So other flash drives and external drives work on this TV **and other TVs**, and this particular flash drive doesn't work on _any TV_? Is the flash drive USB 2.0 or 3.0. If it is 3.0 do the devices support 3.0? Have you tried other 3.0 on them? 2.0 will work on 3.0 ports, but 3.0 will not work on 2.0 ports. Looks like the TV innately has 1 USB 2.0 port, but there might be a firmware upgrade? I suspect your drive is 3.0. What else do you use that drive on? A computer with USB 3.0?

Comment: Exactly. I have tried this on a Sony TV and an LG one. No luck. Its a USB 2.0 drive purchased two years back. The HDTV is less than a year old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a compatibility issue since it does not work on other TV's, try doing a long format of the corsair and then put only one file you know is compatible with media play on the drive.

Does any other thumb drive work on that TV?

Some notes from the user guide, not saying you have not read them already.

.
[image]

.
[image]

.
[image]

Comment: I have formatted it both in FAT32 and NTFS formats, using both quick format and long format. Added a single DivX file which worked played perfectly in other thumb drives connected to the TV. From the notes : I have tried the first. Done the second with _only_ the thumb drive connected. Since its a thumb drive, I am assuming it's an MSC device. And yes, I have connected it directly every time.

Comment: I guess the TV just does not like it for some reason, yes most all thumb drives are MSC class devices, I would sent a note to Samsung support about the issue, see what they have to say, they have live chat or email to contact them.

Comment: That’s probably the case. Something about the drive is unusual/non-standard, which the TV does not support. I can plug a USB flash-drive into my computer and use it and can do the same with an SD card via an SD-to-USB adapter. However while I can plug the same USB flash-drive into my DVD player and watch AVIs from it, the SD-to-USB adapter won’t work. Unfortunately “standards” just aren’t as standard as they used to be.

Comment: Upon searching further, I found [this](http://forum.corsair.com/v3/showthread.php?t=94874) where Corsair says that most TV/DVD players won't recognize the drive because they use a USB HUB based controller to improve performance. But isn't USB HUB some sort of standard ? Shouldn't the TV be compatible with it ?

Comment: Marking this correct since it did point me to the oddity in my pen drive's non-standard USB implementation. Thumb drive won't work with the hard disk but atleast I know why. Avoiding Corsair pen drives from now on.

Comment: Your TV manufacturer did say "USB HUB are not supported", does not matter if it is inside the flash drive or not, evidently. Good to know this little information gem about Corsair flash drives. It appears TV manufacturers need to issue firmware updates to address this hub issue, since most flash drive makers are using it.